# How to convert weather code into a class function?

Tags: python

I am trying to makes this code into a class function, can someone please help me with this? I am not getting the proper output when I run the code.
Thanks in advance

```
img = Image.open("weather.png")
img = img.resize((150,150))
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)

class Weather:
    def __init__(self):
    
    self.m8Frame = Frame()
    self.m8Frame.pack(expand=YES,fill=X)
    self.m8Frame.place(x=140,y=70)

    locationLabel = Label(self.m8Frame ,font =("Calibri Bold", 20), bg = "white")
    locationLabel.grid(row = 0 , sticky = "N", padx=100)
    temperatureLabel = Label(self.m8Frame ,font =("Calibri Bold", 70), bg = "white")
    temperatureLabel.grid(row = 1 , sticky = "W", padx=40)
    Label(self.m8Frame , image= img, bg="white").grid(row=1,sticky="E")
    weatherPredictionLabel = Label(self.m8Frame , font = ("Calibri bold",15), bg ="white")
    weatherPredictionLabel.grid(row=2,stick="W", padx=40)
    
    self.locationLabel.pack()
    self.temperatureLabel.pack()
    self.weatherPredictionLabel.pack()

def getWeather(self):
    self.page = requests.get(url)
    self.soup = BeautifulSoup(self.page.content, "html.parser")
    self.location = self.soup.find ('h1', class_="CurrentConditions--location--kyTeL").text
    self.temperature = self.soup.find('span', class_="CurrentConditions--tempValue--3a50n").text
    self.weatherPrediction = self.soup.find('div', class_= "CurrentConditions--phraseValue--2Z18W").text
    
    self.locationLabel.config(text=self.location)
    self.temperatureLabel.config(text=self.temperature)
    self.weatherPredictionLabel.config(text=self.weatherPrediction)

    self.temperatureLabel.after(60000, self.getWeather)

    threading.Thread(target=Weather).start()
```

'''

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am just trying to learn how to write a class function and I am not sure if my implementations are correct. I will look further into this and try to see where I went wrong. Thanks